# Any size limitations for flex_spi_nor_flash_read APIs?

Tags: spi, nxp-microcontroller

Iam trying to write in to a octal spi flash, and Iam using a MIMXRT1176DVMAA nxp chipset to write in to the flash. But iam facing issues with writing more than 256 bytes in to the flash . But when I use the TI based board iam able to write more than 256 bytes. Is there any limitation , which restricts the flash read and write  to 256 bytes using the flexspi API. Please some one help on this . Any helps are appreciated.I did not see any limitations specified on this in the documentation.

How to write more than 256 bytes in to the OSPI Flash using the NXP IMX APIs.